# How get a text after close dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I create a dialog class like below, thats get user input and then user can ok or cancel.

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
//String username= "hello"
//getter set
String getName(){
    username = this.name;
    return username; 
}
}
```

i call that with this code in my activity

```
custumButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {               
            TextView txtTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tmptextView1);
            mosi.show();
            txtName.setText(mosi.getName());
        }
    });
```

every things works good but when i cal mosi.gettime() every time return defualt value and not send the user input.
i create a toast in my dialog and when user input name it work but when sumbit dialog not show the Inputname in my activity textview

please help me 
and sorry for bad english

***********************

*************************
i **solve** this problem by override ok button setOnClickListener dialog with this code

```
Button mo = (Button)mosi.findViewById(R.id.btnTimepickerOk);
            mo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    txtName.setText(mosi.getName());
                    mosi.dismiss();
                }

            });
```

Comment: my whole of dialog class of 1500 line,if you want to understand the variable change? yes it change and show change in toast but cant send it to class

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to directley get input from your dialog in your listener. For example

```
((EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.input)).getText();
```

To achieve it, you may need to declare your dialog as final, but that's not a problem.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for yr reply, but i set the input in an string and then get that string icant use yr code in my activity.